# Tika PDF reader inserts weird spacing in words (hyphen like)

Tags: java, pdf, apache-tika

I am using TIKA java library to read the content of some PDFs and it seems like it inserts some weird (hyphen-like) spacing. For example:

> The es tab lish ment of an in te grated Part ner Re la tion ship Man age ment
>   (PRM) sys tem can po ten tially ad dress sev eral as pets

I tried to extract text from the same PDF using the `pdftotext` command line utility it extracts the text correctly:

> The establishment of an integrated Partner Relationship Management
>   (PRM) system can potentially address several aspects

Does somebody have any idea why TIKA behaves in this way and any tips to fixing it?

Best regards,
Augusto

Comment: Did you try following the advice given [to your duplicate post to the Tika users list](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/Zf289hhms3sc5hc)? Specifically, what happens when you try the PDFBox tool?

Comment: The same happens, I just posted a message to the PDFBox mailing list also. Lets see what they say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue tracked in the PDFBox Jira. Its description matches the described behavior: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2425

Comment: Apparently it was this issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3248 - it will be fixed in a future release